# Selected item is not highlighted in LWC Tree Grid in Google Chrome

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, chrome

I use LWC and Tree Grid data strcuture.

My component looks like this in Firefox, Safari:

[image]

But it's not highlighted in Chrome:

[image]

How to make it work in Chrome? As most of people use it as default browser.

Comment: Hi, What you have tried so far? Please add the relevant code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is an SLDS issue. Open below url in Chrome and Safari you will see even in the documentation it doesn't work on Chrome.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tree/example

I applied aria-selected="true" manually and it worked. If this is crucial for you maybe you can try the same.